# Assertion failure when trying to insert into sqlite database on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I really get frustrated with the error .I have spent two days in for getting solve that .But it not get fix ,When getting data from database at that time there no problem .But when fire the insert statement.I get this errors:

Assertion failure in -[NewJourney addJourney], /Users/HarishYadav/Desktop/JourneyMapper/Journey/NewJourney.m:114
2011-07-05 17:23:13.739 Journey[24328:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while inserting data. 'database is locked''
*** Call stack at first throw:

Here is my code for inserting the value in database

-(void)addJourney
{
    if (addStmt == nil)
    {

```
    const char * sql = "insert into UserJourney(JourneyName,LocationName,Description) Values (?,?,?)";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1,&addStmt ,NULL) != SQLITE_OK)

        NSAssert1(0,@"Error while creating add statement. '%s'",sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    }
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [journeyname UTF8String], -1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [journeylocation UTF8String],-1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [journeydescription UTF8String],-1 , SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt)) 

        NSAssert1(0,@"Error while inserting data. '%s'",sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    else 

        journeyID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
```

}

What was the problem in this

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems database is accessed from somewhere else. That's why it says database is locked. Try debug you app use NSZombie. I prefer use FMDB for sqlite purpose.

Comment: Yes my database get access from other class

Comment: Jignesh is right use finalize statement and see if it works or not. But I prefer FMDB for sqlite. It is very easy to implement easy to debug and you don't have to do a lot of struggling with SQLite. FMDB will handle all the things.

Comment: @Rahul I don't know how to use the FMDB.I right now i am using sqlite database .I think it get mess .

Comment: if your app is at completion stage stick with sqlite. But for future use FMDB.

Comment: @Rahul How to use NSZombie For checking the sqlite error.Can you send me that steps please

Comment: Double click on executables->yourAppName below the target in your left side panel in xcode. You can see there a tab named Arguments. Add NSZombieEnabled and value = YES in the lower box.

Comment: It will show more useful information then the normal crash report. You will see when your app crash while debugging in gdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use after you complete your statement

> sqlite3_finalize(statement);

in every function where you use database interaction.

Comment: sqlite3_finalize function commits all transactions into database, if you dont do sqlite3_finalize after you insert/update/select data to/from database, sqlite will create journal file and this file will become temporarily available, when you do sqlite3_finalize, it will be committed to database. so meanwhile, it will be locked.

Comment: I have function +(void)finalizeStatements
{
 if (database) sqlite3_close(database);
 if (database) sqlite3_finalize(deleteStmt);
 if (database) sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);
 if (database) sqlite3_finalize(detailStmt);
 if (database) sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
 
}

Comment: I call this (void)finalizeStatements in to the appdelegate's       - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application  {
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
 [self.journeyList makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(saveAllData)];
 [NewJourney finalizeStatements];
 }

Comment: I think, at every statement, you need to call sqlite3_finalize function

Answer (score 0):

check that your database is opened or not?

```
if(sqlite3_open([temppath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
```

Comment: @ Rakesh Bhatt How can check that data base is open or not?

Comment: Ok Is you have any other sample project which help me to add ,delete,updata and display on row project help me .I try this sample code project http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/10/sqlite-tutorial-loading-data-as.html. Is that you have any other link which help me out from this condition .